# Haxe, ListSort.sort() issue

Tags: haxe

```
var persons: List<Person> = readPersonsFile("persons.txt");
ListSort.sort(persons, function(personA, personB): Int
{
    return Person.compare(personA.first(), personB.first());
});
```

I'm just trying to sort this list. It's giving me this error:

```
Constraint check failure for sort.T
List<Person> should be { prev : List<Person>, next : List<Person> }
List<Person> has no field next
```

Which is wierd to me, because it sounds like it's wanting me to pass an implicit object with  two different lists, which if that's really the way... that's not very insulated if that's true.

Comment: `haxe.ds.ListSort` is not designed to sort elements in `List<T>`. It's main purpose is to sort "custom" linked elements with next & prev properties.
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/ds/ListSort.hx

Comment: Are you sure `readPersonsFile()` returns a List? Maybe it is `null`, you might want to do a `if(persons!=null)` first. I think ListSort suggest it sorts a List so I assume it should work.

Comment: I know readPersonsFile() is not returning null, because these errors are in building the file.  Mihail Ignatiev, if haxe.ds.ListSort is not meant to sort a List, than what is? Because I looked at ArraySort, but that's meant for Array?

Answer (score 2):

`ListSort` is only [supposed to work](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/haxe/ds/ListSort.hx) on singly or doubly linked lists; the `List` class is neither of these (although it does share some APIs with them, but with different time and space costs).

In your case, you can probably change `readPersonsFile` to return either an `Array` or a `haxe.ds.GenericStack`, and use either `persons.sort(cmp)` or `ListSort.sortSingleLinked(persons.head, cmp)`.

Also, if necessary, you can easily convert any iterable – that is, any object that has an `iterator:Void->Iterator<T>` method – into an array with `Lambda.array(iterable)`.

---

*The [documentation](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/ListSort.html) is lacking the necessary constraints on the `T` parameters.  This is a bug in the documentation generator that I'll try to report soon.*

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see `haxe.ds.ListSort` is supposed to work on linked-list like structures, not Haxe Lists. If all you want to do is sort a list might be easier to simply use an `Array`. If your goal is to use this particular type of sorting and want to avoid using arrays (because of memory limits for example) you just need to provide it with a structure like:

```
typedef PersonListItem = {
    var prev:PersonListItem;
    var next:PersonListItem;
    var person:Person;
}
```

(like the `ListItem` used internally by Haxe List actually)

But I assume you want to just sort "a list". So if that's what you are after it may look like this:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var persons:Array<Person> = readPersonsFile("persons.txt");
        trace(persons.join(","));
        persons.sort(Person.compare);
        trace(persons.join(","));
        trace(persons[0]);
    }

    static function readPersonsFile(name:String):Array<Person> {
        var result = new Array<Person>();
        result.push(new Person(8));
        result.push(new Person(1));
        result.push(new Person(2));
        result.push(new Person(6));
        result.push(new Person(0));
        result.push(new Person(9));
        result.push(new Person(3));
        result.push(new Person(7));
        result.push(new Person(4));
        result.push(new Person(5));
        return result;
    }
}

class Person {
    var id:Int;

    public function new(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static function compare(a:Person, b:Person):Int {
        return a.id - b.id;
    }

    public function toString():String {
        return 'Person($id)';
    }
}
```